# Need help resolving an error relating to Maps and HashMap in my Java Program

Tags: java, hashmap, maps, mismatch

Whenever I use the following line of code:

```
Map<Integer, Integer> result = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
```

I always end up[ getting the error below:

```
Type mismatch: cannot convert from HashMap<Integer,Integer> to Map<Integer,Integer>
```

I attempted using a cast already and suppressing the warnings, but then when I run the program I just get an Exception as shown below:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.TreeMap cannot be cast to Map
    at Data.casesByMonth(Data.java:242)
    at Data.main(Data.java:26)
```

EDIT: For those asking, here is the casesByMonth() implementation:

```
public Map<Integer, Integer> casesByMonth() {
    Map<Integer, Integer> result = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
    for (Event event : list) {
        if (!result.containsKey(event.date.getMonth()))
            result.put(event.date.getMonth(), event.cases);
        else {
            int c = result.get(event.date.getMonth());
            c += event.cases;
            result.put(event.date.getMonth(), c);
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: can you share the `casesByMonth` method implementation?

Comment: Please check `Map` class. Probably you defined it somewhere in your code and it overlaps `java.util.Map`.

Comment: @Anothercoder I have added the implementation in

Comment: @BlaidenKirk can you check for imports as per Timur's comment.

Comment: @Anothercoder There is no overlap for import use. I am utilizing java.util.* and did not define the Map class anywhere else in the Data class

Comment: @Anothercoder I also don't know if this helps, but both Sets and Lists work when converting TreeSets and ArrayLists